# turn off soap extension on webmethod

Tags: .net, soap

It possible turn off soap extension on webmethod ?
Something like this :

```
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapExtensionClass]
    public void func()
    {
        if(b)
        {
        // turn off soap extension on web method
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should do the check for `b` inside the SOAP extension class, not in the web service method. If SOAP extension class is not your own, then create a wrapper class around that and specify that on your method.